# Работа с Twitter

Tags: c++, twitter, соцсети

Народ, у меня появилась идея. Хочу написать программу которая будет автоматически отправлять сообщения в Twitter. Может кто рассказать или кинуть пару сылок на инструкции как такое можно сделать.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries#cplusplus

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/twitcurl/